# Virtuemart bulk upload module

Tags: joomla, virtuemart

I'm looking for a Virtuemart bulk upload module. I have surfed for ages now, but can't find anything, does anyone know a sollution for this?

Answer (score 0):

I've used [CSVImproved](http://www.csvimproved.com) and it does the trick